Construct a Blob without MIME Type?
I use a nodejs public API that allow me to send some attachments in a chat. This public API ask me a Buffer and construct a Blob from my provided buffer, just like that :
body.append('attachments', new Blob([buffer]), filename);

Is that a problem that the API don't ask for a MIME Type (and not use the 'options' parameter of Blob constructor) ?
Some attachment are working using this API, some others are not. So ->
Why the MIME Type is optional when you construct a Blob, and what can happened if you construct the Blob without specifying MIME Type ?
(FYI: The buffer that I provide only contain the bytes of the attachment, no header or anything else).
